# Setting up a new mac to avoid "system" folders like Documents, Music, Desktop, etc

Tags: macos, zsh, user-profiles, home-directory

As a computational scientist, I spend a lot of time working on my macbook pro at the command line. I'm setting up a new laptop and it's time to rethink some of my setup.

It's always bothered me that the apple setup gives me a bunch of folders in my home directory that I don't want to see every time I'm `cd`ing around my file system (folders like `Documents`, `Music`, `Pictures`, `Library`, etc.) It's also inconvenient that whenever I do a `find . -name [mymissingfile.jl]` in my home directory that I get a bunch of errors when the find tries to look in Library but doesn't have permission.

At one point, I worked to remove or re-place these folders elsewhere but this hasn't worked out for me.

Does anyone have any suggestions how to get a cleaner setup? Without all these "extra" folders getting in the way?

One thought is just to place my "home" directory one directory deeper: instead of `/Users/myname` use something like `/Users/me/myrealhome` so that the vexing folders are in `me` but I'm always starting in `myrealhome` (by setting Terminal to open new shells there, by default). If I do that, can I change `$HOME` to be `Users/me/myrealhome`? So that `cd ~` takes me where I want to go?

Any better ideas? Other thoughts?

Comment: If you don't get a useful answer here, you may want to consider whether your question is appropriate for [apple.se].

Comment: As a computational scientist, you might consider trying Linux instead.  I am NOT A BIGGOT.  I don't care what OS you use; however, Linux allows for more finite control of what happens in your operating system whereas macos is more of a one size fits all environment.  You might even consider using a Linux VM under your mac environment.

Comment: Might be tougher with a laptop, as it would have to be external, but on a Mac Pro with 6 drives in it, I just don't use the boot drive for 'real' work.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I think you mean "more fine-grained control". "more finite" suggests that the control is more restricted.

Comment: Thanks for the lesson mr smart @Barmar :) .. never stop learning right? .. My point was still valid even if I was too stupid to express it correctly :P

Answer (score 1):

As you suggested I create other "functional" folders for development and do not try to disturb the MacOS architected folders like Documents, Downloads, ... because so many products depend on that layout.  For me I am a developer and I created a ./Development folder and then put the various git repositories in there as well as tools.  This let's me scope searches and other activities for scanning, etc.

Messing with the architected structure causes too much pain when installing other software.

Comment: Agreed. After that it's only a matter of keeping an eye on some software as a lot of them default to one of those folders when saving files (DefaultFolderX helps with that).